# Lock tables in long stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, table-lock

I have a stored procedure in oracle to delete rows from some 8-10 tables.
I have to delete a row from say table "Person". It has lot of relations like "Person_Health", "Person_Claims", "Person_Bills" etc. Again, the child tables has relations with other tables.

I have written a stored procedure, and looped through the children tables to delete the child records, and then finally deleted the record in parent table. **I'm not using any kind of lock/wait mechanisms** (I'm a beginner, not sure about which one to use)

Sometimes, this procedure is failing. **Translating SQLException with SQL state '61000', error code '60', message [ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource**

Problem is, it is failing frequently because of the (select/insert/update)requests to access these tables from different parts of application while this stored procedure is executing.

Is there a way to lock the tables individually while deleting? Or is there any other better way to do this.

Note: one way might be to put "**ON DELETE CASCADE**", for these tables, which will automatically delete the child records, but that is not **possible**.

Comment: Read about this [lock_table](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/transactions/lock_table.php) , anyway in your procedure , before update you can check **V$Locked_Object** and decide to update or not

Comment: What do you mean by "failing"?  Are you trying to select for update with NOWAIT and getting "ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired"?  Or something else?  If you were to just delete child1, delete child2, ... then there would be no error just a long wait while you waited for the other session to commit.

Comment: `it is failing frequently because of the (select/insert/update)requests to access these tables from different parts of application` - well, it you lock tables for a long time, then your application start failing, or at last it hangs.Usesr probably start to compalain..

Comment: why is on delete cascade not possible?

Comment: @tbone because DBA said so

Comment: @TonyAndrews Updated the Question. Deadlock exception.
I'm not using any kind of lock/wait mechanisms as i'm a beginner and no idea about them. Please suggest one.

Comment: Have your dba get you the trace files created on a deadlock.  Locking an entire table is a very, very, very bad idea.

Comment: Are your constraints deferrable?  They probably should be.  Another approach is to do a soft delete (set a status flag in the parent as Inactive or similar).

Comment: @tbone sorry didn't get you. Can you please elaborate a bit